# Nonlinear Difference Equation Solved by Substitution

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm reading *Introduction to Dynamic Systems* by David Luenberger. Question 2.1 asks to solve a nonlinear difference equation
$$
y(k+1) = \frac{y(k)}{b + y(k)} \quad \text{for } k=1, 2, \ldots
$$
He recommends using a change of variables to convert into a linear difference equation and then solve.

Writing out $y(k+3)$ shows a pattern
$$
y(k+3) = \frac{y(k)}{b^3 + (b^2 + b + 1) y(k)}.
$$
The denominator is a geometric sequence
$$
1 + b + b^2 + \cdots + b^{k-1} = \frac{1-b^k}{1-b}
$$
with an identity that can be substituted and written out in general as
$$
y(k+1) = \frac{y(k)}{b^k + \frac{1-b^k}{1-b} y(k)}.
$$
However I do not know how to find the solution of this problem either.

Would anyone have an idea how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $ x(k) = \frac{1}{A + y(k)} $, where A is a constant, in the equation. There will be a cross term $x(k)x(k+1)$ where the coefficient is a function of A. Choose A appropriately to get a linear difference equation for $ x(k) $. In this particular case, A is zero. But, in general, A may be obtained by solving a quadratic equation.